# Load textdomain in the website, not in the admin, based on user settings not general settings

Tags: textdomain

When you load textdomain with `load_theme_textdomain()` hooked on **'after_setup_theme'** it loads your translations both in the admin and on the website, but it translate the website based on the option **"site language"** under general settings not **"language"** under Profile / Personal options, that means that the site is translated for all users at once based on a single setting "site language" not for each individual user, so it doesnt allow to translate the site for each one of theme as in the admin.

Is there a way to load textdomain based on the "language" option for each individual user?

This is how im loading the textdomain:

```
   add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'load_textdomain' );
  
    function load_textdomain(){
        
        load_theme_textdomain( 'wpkit', get_template_directory() . '/assets/lang' );
        
    }
```